# R extract the first pattern from the end of string

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract sizes from strings, which can be:

```
a <- c("xxxxxxx 2.5 oz (23488)",
        "xxxxx /1.36oz",
        "xxxxx/7 days /20 ml")
```

Result I want: `2.5 oz     /1.36oz     /20 ml`

Because strings varies, so I want to extract patterns backward. That is, I want to extract the first appearance of `\\/*(\\d+\\.*\\d*)\\s*[[:alpha:]]+` from the end of the string. It will avoid R from taking  `23488` from the first string and `/7 days` from the third string.

Anyone knows how I can achieve this? 
Thanks!

Comment: An idea is to put `.*` before to consume. Something like [`^.*[ \/]\b([\d.]+\s*[a-z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/QoEhBj/4)

Comment: won't it capture everything up to and including size?

Comment: @Mr369 yes it will. For the result you're looking for, just refer to capture group 1

Comment: @emsimpson92 You changed the regex and it won't match, say, `40 l` now.

Comment: @Mr369 Without capturing group: [`^.*[ \/]\b\K[\d.]+\s*[a-z]+`](https://regex101.com/r/QoEhBj/5) (with `perl=true`).

Comment: @bobblebubble: why include `\b`? Seems to work fine without it. Also, can you explain the use of `\K`?

Comment: @Nettle I used the word boundary to force the next part `[\d.]` to start with a word character which can only be a digit (exclude to start with `.`).  [`\K` is used to reset beginning of the reported match](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K). The part before that is consumed can be seen similar a variable width lookbehind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
> a <- c("xxxxxxx 2.5 oz (23488)",
+         "xxxxx /1.36oz",
+         "xxxxx/7 days /20 ml")
> regmatches(a, regexpr("/?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s*\\p{L}+(?!.*\\d(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s*\\p{L}+)", a, perl=TRUE))
[1] "2.5 oz"  "/1.36oz" "/20 ml"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ek8V3F/1).

**Details**

- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `\\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\\.\\d+)?` - an optional `.` and 1+ digits sequence
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\\p{L}+` - 1+ letters
- `(?!.*\\d(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s*\\p{L}+)` - not followed with

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
  - `\\d`  - a digit
  - `(?:\\.\\d+)?` - an optional `.` and 1+ digits sequence
  - `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\\p{L}+` - 1+ letters

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! while how about the case where the string is `"xxxxx 08/21/1.38 Oz xxx 08/21/18 xxx 08/21/18"` ? Using the regexp will result `18 xxx` instead.

Comment: @Mr369 Then, as per your specs, you should better extract all matches and then grab only the last occurrences, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/N7OuPC).

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the units(oz, ml, etc), you could try something like this:

`((\d*|\d*\.\d{0,2})\s?(ml|oz|etc))`

See [working example](https://regex101.com/r/bLRpQH/1).

Comment: FYI: This requires the knowledge of all measurement units.